# preg_match after certain string and only number

Tags: php, preg-match

so I have this string   `alert('price = USD 1,313,000');`   it's inside html tag

, I'm trying to `preg_match` the string after 
    `alert('price ,`

how do I get only `1,313,000` ?

Answer (score 0):

You can extract your value with:

```
$message = "alert('price = USD 1,313,000');";
$result = array();
preg_match("/([0-9,]+)/", $message, $result);
```

will return an array:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 1,313,000
    [1] => 1,313,000
)
```

Assumin the message is always like that. If the message change, may be you will have to work again on the regular expression.

[preg_match documentation](http://php.net/preg_match)

It will also work for

```
$message = "alert('price = USD 1,313,000');alert('tax = USD 15,000');";
$result = array();
preg_match("/price = USD ([0-9,]+)/", $message, $result);
print_r($result);
```

Then you will have

```
Array
(
    [0] => price = USD 1,313,000
    [1] => 1,313,000
)
```

In which case you have to take the `$result[1]` because it is representing the sub part with `( )` and not the whole matching string which is represented by `$result[0]`.

Comment: the string I mentioned above is only a part in html response, so this number "1,313,000" not the only number

Comment: what im doing is preg_match('/alert\(\'price(.*)/',$str,$m);
how can I get the only number

Comment: `[0-9,]+` mean "one or more number or ,"

Comment: yes I know , but I only want the number after string price, so any way to do it??

Comment: there's another string like alert(tax = USD 30,01 ) inside the html

I want only number after string "alert(price = "

Comment: Yes, and the code I wrote is **working** also for this example. try the code. Here is an example online : http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/3dcc03da85cb5ad6280307de3a2fea514da266a3

Comment: lets say the string $message = "alert('price = USD 1,313,000');alert('tax = USD 15,000');"
how can I get number only after "price" ?? I dont want number after tax

Comment: Please mark as best answer if my answer is responding to your initial question.

Comment: can we do it without "USD" ?? sometimes currency changes

Comment: Try with `preg_match("/price = [a-zA-Z]+ ([0-9,]+)/", $message, $result);` and please mark your best answer if my aswer is helping you :)